# ¿Cómo crear una custom key al almacenar los datos repetidos de un array a un nuevo objeto en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente código el cual almacena en un objeto el número de veces que se repite un autor en el array recorrido, pero lo que me almacena en el objeto es el nombre del autor como llave y el número de veces que se repite como valor, cuando lo que deseo es crear una llave llamada author y que se almacene el nombre del autor y una llave llamada blogs y el número de veces que se repite.

Esto es lo que se almacena en mi objeto

```
{Michael Chan: 1, Edsger W. Dijkstra: 2, Robert C. Martin: 3}
```

Pero el resultado que espero y que no logro entender como hacerlo es el siguiente

```
{
  author: 'Michael Chan', 
  blogs: 1
},
{
  author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', 
  blogs: 2
},
{
  author: 'Robert C. Martin'
  blogs: 3
}
```

**Código en Codesandbox**

Adjunto el código hecho el cual corre únicamente en consola para comprobaciones.

[image: Edit quirky-dewdney-zqbur]

Comment: Deberías incluir el código como texto y no con un enlace externo, porque podría cambiar o desaparecer en el futuro, como el caso de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/463055/54039).

Comment: Gracias compa, edité el archivo original de codesandbox para que se mantenga así siempre porque hice las pruebas en otro archivo.

Comment: El tema es que sirve más el código en tu propia pregunta que en un sitio externo porque es más fácil copiarlo, por lo que la idea general es: ayúdanos para tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otr solución. En esta se busca el autor en la lista si está se aumentan los blogs y si no se crea una nueva entrada de la lista de autores. La búsqueda en el array de blogs se hace comarando los campos **author** de las entrada de ambas listas. Toda la operación se hace de una vez, en un solo bucle.

```js
const blogs = [
  {
    _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
    title: 'React patterns',
    author: 'Michael Chan',
    url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/',
    likes: 7,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
    title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url:
      'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html',
    likes: 5,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
    title: 'Canonical string reduction',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html',
    likes: 12,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
    title: 'First class tests',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url:
      'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll',
    likes: 10,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
    title: 'TDD harms architecture',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url:
      'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html',
    likes: 0,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
    title: 'Type wars',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html',
    likes: 2,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const mostBlogs = (blogList) => {
  let blogAuthor = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < blogList.length; i++) {
        ind= blogAuthor.findIndex((v)=>v.author == blogList[i].author);
        if(ind>=0)
            blogAuthor[ind].blogs++;
        else{
            blogAuthor.push({'author':blogList[i].author, 'blogs':1});
        }  
  }

  console.log(blogAuthor);
};

mostBlogs(blogs);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compa.

Answer (score 3):

Una solución podría ser utilizar [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para mapear o "convertir" una arreglo con una estructura a otro con otra estructura diferente.

```js
const obj = {
  "Michael Chan": 1,
  "Edsger W. Dijkstra": 2,
  "Robert C. Martin": 3
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(authorName => ({
  autor: authorName,
  blogs: obj[authorName]
})));
```

Con [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) obtenemos los nombres de los autores como un arreglo (`["Michael Chan", "Edsger W. Dijkstra", "Robert C. Martin"]` ).

Una vez que tenemos el arreglo, nada más mapeamos cada valor (cada autor) con la nueva estructura deseada con `map()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias compa.

Answer (score 2):

Añadiendo un for con clave valor armas tu objeto y se lo asignas al array
espero te funcione

```js
const blogs = [
  {
    _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
    title: 'React patterns',
    author: 'Michael Chan',
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
    title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
    title: 'Canonical string reduction',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
    title: 'First class tests',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
    title: 'TDD harms architecture',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
    title: 'Type wars',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  }
];

const mostBlogs = (blogList) => {
  let blogAuthor = {};
  let authors = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < blogList.length; i++) {
    if (blogList[i].author in blogAuthor) {
      ++blogAuthor[blogList[i].author];
    } else {
      blogAuthor[blogList[i].author] = 1;
    }
  }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(blogAuthor)) {
    const author = {author: key, blogs: value};
    authors.push(author)
  }
  console.log(authors)
};

mostBlogs(blogs);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compa.